# Retraction on non-compact Stiefel manifold

Tags: optimization, riemannian-geometry, retraction, stiefel-manifolds

I have been looking online for the retraction of the non-compact Stiefel manifold (where $k <m$): $R_*^{m \times k} = \{ M \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times k} : \operatorname{rk}(M)=k \}$ as seen [here (table 4)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.0430.pdf) which links to [there (Example 4.1.5)](https://assets.press.princeton.edu/chapters/absil/Absil_Chap4.pdf) or [here (section 3.4)](https://sites.uclouvain.be/absil/2013-04/low_rank_retraction_13PA_techrep.pdf). I have read it to be $R_X(\dot{X}) = X + \dot{X}$ where $X \in \mathbb{R}_*^{m \times k}$ and $\dot{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times k}$ i.e. $\dot{X}$ is in the tangent space $T_X \mathbb{R}_*^{m \times k}$. But the retraction should give a full rank matrix ? How is adding any $m \times k$ matrix going to ensure it ?

Comment: Linking to PDF files is not very polite.  arXiv provides DOI links for a reason

Comment: its all from official sites. You responding just to say this is not very polite

Comment: PDF files can be several megabytes heavy.  The abstract is a couple of kilobytes only.  Why force people to waste data just to check who the authors are?